# Unable to have multiple sessions to run @app.route which triggers a python script

Tags: python, flask

I am testing a flask app to run a python script which will generate 500,000 random numbers from which it will sorted out the top 6 most appeared number.

I will key "http://localhost:5000/gen" in the address bar and need to wait for about 30 mins for the result. This is working fine.

However, if I click on another browser tab to launch another session of "http://localhost:5000/gen" while the first one is still running,  it will just hang there. It can only be run when the first session has completed with the return result.

I thought that shouldn't flask be able to take care of multiple sessions since it is a web engine.

Any advice on how to accomplish this will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

```
@app.route('/gen')
def start_gen():
    # run the python script to generate 500,000 numbers and return top 6  
    # most generated number

    results = str(gen()) 

    return render_template('results.html',the_results = results)
```

Comment: 30 minutes is a really long time to find the top 6 of 500,000 random numbers. I know it doesn’t answer your question, but can you show the source of `gen()`?

Comment: Also, which version of Flask are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Flask's built-in server is only meant to be used for development, and as such, it defaults to a single thread and can only handle one request at a time.

You can [set up a Standalone WSGI container](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) to serve concurrent requests - it is also a practical method for deployment.

Alternatively, you may [pass *options* to flask.Flask.run()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run), which will be passed to [werkzeug](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)  # run the flask server in threaded mode
```

or

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(processes=10)  # run up to 10 concurrent processes
```